# Docker - no access to other containers in the network during docker image build

Tags: docker, tcp, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two docker containers: simple rest api and a database. I want to start the rest api only when the database is ready. I tried several solutions, when i figured out the problem is in the network.

[wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script works perfectly fine when I start rest api without waiting for the database and then do `docker exec -it <api-container-name> bash` and run it from there. When I'm trying to run it as a `CMD` in Dockerfile it can't establish connection with the database. Same thing happens when I start the api while database is already running.

Api dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN chmod +x Scripts/wait-for-it.sh
RUN Scripts/wait-for-it.sh -t 30 172.20.1.2:3306 #times out when waiting for database
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/Atlanta.dll"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24

services:
  main-db:
    container_name: main-db
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Main
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5000:3306"
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2

  atlanta-ms:
    container_name: atlanta
    build:
      context: ./Atlanta
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: atlanta:ms
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.3
```

Comment: Why are you trying to connect during the _build_ of the API?

Comment: I have to do an entity framework database migration so i have to know when the db is up

Comment: What command are you running for the build? Assuming the compose stack is running as well during the API build?

Comment: docker-compose up -d main-db
docker-compose up --build atlanta-ms

Answer (score 1):

<s>I see your confusion.</s>

The `RUN` statement isn't doing what you think it is; it's running the `wait-for-it.sh` while the container is building, and isn't under the docker-compose's control. ***It will not run when your container runs!*** You should check out the documentation from docker about [container start-up order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) and `docker-compose`.

Detached mode for your database will have no effect on build/run process; expect you won't be able to interact with it.

Using docker-compose will, by default, have all the container in non-interactive mode; but that's okay because [you can still attach/detach to the containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/).

You should add a `depends-on` option to your `docker-compose.yml` and add your `wait-for-it.sh` to the `command` option in the `docker-compose.yml`, not the `Dockerfile`.

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24

services:
  main-db:
    container_name: main-db
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Main
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5000:3306"
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2

  atlanta-ms:
    container_name: atlanta
    build:
      context: ./Atlanta
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    # Add this `depends-on`
    depends-on: 
      - "main-db"

    # Add this `command` option
    command: ["Scripts/wait-for-it.sh", "-t", "30", "172.20.1.2:3306"]

    image: atlanta:ms
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.3
```

I would recommend moving `wait-for-it.sh` to your [`WORKDIR`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir), and make sure it is passed as `"./wait-for-it.sh"` to `command`, just to make your life easier.

Don't forget to ***remove*** `RUN Scripts/wait-for-it.sh -t 30 172.20.1.2:3306` from your `Dockerfile`! (Because `docker-compose` is handling it now.)

And remember that the command for using `docker-compose` is [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/), unless, that is, you'd like to use [`docker swarm`](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/) instead.

Comment: I don't think OP is confused about this, he actually does want to run the step during build (from the comments under the original post anyway).

Comment: Thats right. I tried running it exactly as you do it here before and it didn't work as well. The script didn't even actually run.

Comment: @johnharris85 Thanks for pointing that out, I see what trouble the OP is having -- that's not easy

Comment: @dudinii Are you standing up a containerized database to migrate into a new database, running it, then migrating it to a new container?

Comment: I'm running contenerized database, but it takes time to set up. I want to start container with asp.net core api right after starting that database container and do the "dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration" command to update database tables with my api current model. It connects with that database and runs some sql scripts. Database connection works good when the api container is running, but it doesnt during build.

Comment: @dudinii What happens if you ignore what I said about removing the `RUN` command for `wait-for-it.sh`, and go ahead with `docker-compose up`? Have you tried to build this in with `docker swarm init`? Docker-compose and docker swarm do things differently, so that may change the outcome.

Comment: I would rather not use docker swarm nor kubernetes here. Compose should be enough. I will keep looking for solution and post here if i find something.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I managed to solve my problem. I can guess this is not a clean way of doing it, but it works for now.

I'm building and running both containers first. Then, when both api and db are up, i'm remotely executing migration commands using `docker exec`. `wait-for-it` script is not needed here.

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose up -d --build atlanta-ms main-db
docker exec atlanta bash -c "dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration && dotnet ef database update"
```

rest api Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/Atlanta.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.1.0/24

services:
  main-db:
    container_name: main-db
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "5000:3306"
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.2

  atlanta-ms:
    container_name: atlanta
    build:
      context: ./Atlanta
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: atlanta:ms
    ports:
      - "5001:80"
    networks:
      backend:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.3
```

The drawback of this solution is that rest api is running in detached mode, so i cannot stop it just by doing `ctrl + c` in console. Adding `docker attach atlanta` line at the end of `run.sh` script works (i can stop container by simple `ctrl + c`), but it doesn't work with several containers (cannot attach to more than one container) so i have to write simple stop script and call it independently from `run.sh` to stop containers, what is a little inconvenient.

I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how can i attach to few containers, so i could stop them all with `ctrl + c` (thats how the `docker-compose up service1 service2 service3` without "-d" flag works)